# How to seed the Random Number generator in Rust with a string or a number

Tags: random, rust

I need to seed the Random Number generator in Rust to get deterministic output.

I am using the following to generate a random number:

```
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let mut random_number = rng.gen_range(0.0..1.0);
```

How do I seed this with

1. String; and a
2. Number

Comment: `ThreadRng` is specifically designed to reseed itself from "true" random data at regular intervals, so you can't seed it yourself. You will have to use a [`SeedableRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html) (e.g. created with [`StdRng::from_seed`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html#method.from_seed)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`rand_pcg`](https://crates.io/crates/rand_pcg) crate with `rand_pcg = "0.3.1"` in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
use rand_pcg::Pcg32;
use rand::{Rng, SeedableRng, rngs::StdRng};
let mut rng = Pcg32::seed_from_u64(42);
    
let random_number: u32 = rng.gen_range(0..100);
println!("{}", random_number);
```